# MATLAB conditional min function ignoring the condition?

Tags: matlab, indexing, find, min

I have a *structure* **A** with *fields* **B** and **C**.

Values of B are double and can take on the value of 1 or 2.
Values of C are double and range in value from 1 to about 50.
Both B and C have the same number of elements (when a value is assigned to C then a 1 or 2 is assigned to B).

The following code is supposed to find all index values where B equals 1 and then use those index values to find the minimum value of C.

```
>> a=find(A(1).B(:)==1);

>> [value,index]=min(A(1).C(a))

value =   5.020000000000000
index =   630
```

As you can see below, when I put the minimum value index back into B it returns a 2.

```
>> A(1).B(630)

ans =     2
```

Comment: You are locating the minimum in `A(1)` but looking it up in `A(2)`

Comment: Sorry @MohsenNosratinia that was a typo. It was supposed to be A(1).B(630). Problem remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that vector `a` is not the same size as original vector `A(1).B(:)`. So the value you get in `index` refers to the corresponding location in `a` not in `A(1).C(:)` to get the correct index use:

```
A(1).B(a(index))
```

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't realize it had to be the same size. Thank you. :)